# Trying to find the opposite of this cancan ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I've got a cancan ability that works but I'm looking to get the opposite effect:

```
can :block, Company, id: user.company_id
```

here's what I've tried:

```
can :block, Company, id: !user.company_id
cannot :block, Company, id: user.company_id
cannot :block, Company, :id => user.company_id
can :block, Company, :id => !user.company_id
```

And none work at all.  Can somebody help me define the correct ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
can :block, Company do |company|
  company.id != user.company_id
end
```